# Computing the bound of $d(n)$ the divisor counting "function" of $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, asymptotics, divisor-counting-function

Terrence Tao gives the following [formula](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/) for the bound of the divisor $$d(n)\leq \exp\left(O\left({\log n \above 1.5pt \log \log n}\right)\right)$$

How can I use this formula to explicitly compute a bound? This question is part understanding Big-O notation. For example if $n$ is a prime say $17$. Naively I am computing $\exp\left(O\left(\frac{\log 17}{ \log \log 17}\right)\right)=\exp\left(O\left(13.66\right)\right)$. I am not sure if my steps are correct or the next calculation to make? I am assuming the log is base 10?

Comment: Here is how you should read the formula: There is a constant $C$, independent of $n$, such that for sufficiently large $n$ inequality $d(n)\leq\exp(C\cdot\log n/\log\log n)$ holds. This tells you absolutely nothing about values on specific arguments $n$, because, a priori, you know nothing about the constant $C$.

Comment: Read the rest of the article, everything is explained in details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also an effective version, [due to Robin and Nicolas](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CMB-1983-078-5). See also [Nicolas Survey.](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf)
$$ d(n) \leq n^{\left( \frac{1.0660186782977...}{ \log \log n} \right)} $$
with the constant $1.066..$ chosen to give equality at $n = 6983776800$ and $d(n) = 2304.$ This is superb for larger numbers. For smaller numbers, better to use
$$ d(n) \leq \sqrt {3n} $$ or
$$ d(n) \leq 48 \; \sqrt[3] {\frac{n}{2520}}  $$

Note $$  \frac{1.0660186782977...}{ \log 2} \approx 1.53793986 $$

[image]

Comment: So they key here is the notion of "effective version".

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez I recommend http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf   save it and print it out, it is sideways on the screen. Very helpful.

Comment: I am setting $log\text{ }log\text{ }n=log\left(log\left(n\right)\right)$

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez that is what it means. As far as typesetting, Latex has several functions it calls "log-like" such as cosine, where the function is often used without being followed by any parentheses, just the argument. For such functions, we may just write it twice to indicate composition with itself. If you were uncertain, the logarithm is base $e= 2.718281828459...$ So $\log 16 \approx 2.77$ and $\log \log 16 \approx 1.01978$

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)=O(g(n))$ as $n\to \infty$ means that there exists $k>0$ such that $|f(n))\leq |g(n)|$ for all sufficiently large $n.$ It says nothing about the comparison of $f(n)$ to $g(n)$ for any particular $n.$

We have $$d(n)=\exp \left(O\left(\frac {\log n}{ \log \log n}\right)\right )\iff   \log  d(n)=O\left( \frac { \log n}{\log n \log n}\right).$$  Since $\log d(n)\geq 0,$ and since $(\log n)/\log \log n>0$ for all but finitely many $n\in \mathbb N,$ this means that   there exists $k>0$ such that for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $$\log d(n)\leq k \left(\frac {\log n}{ \log \log  n}\right)=\log (n^{k/\log \log n}).$$  One (obvious) implication of this is that for any  $j>0$ we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {d(n)}{n^j}=0.$$